# Check number of running scripts using ps

Tags: bash, sh, ps

I'm writing a script (show_volume.sh) which may be called several times in short intervals. I need a way to determine whether there is more than just one running instance of this script. I figured I could use `ps`, so I wrote this function in Bash:

```
is_only_process(){
    PCOUNT=`ps -a | grep show_volume.sh | wc -l`
    echo $PCOUNT
    if (( PCOUNT==1 )); then
        return 1 
    fi  
    return 0
}
```

So I added these 2 lines

```
is_only_process
sleep 4
```

and started this script once, but the output of `echo $PCOUNT` does not make any sense to me. I always get the value 2, not 1, as expected. When I run this command

`ps -a | grep show_volume.sh | wc -l`

from another terminal while the script is running, I receive the value 1.
It's pretty much the same when I run this script several times in a row, e.g. 10 times using a for loop. The script itself determines values which are too high while I receive correct values when using another terminal.

Now, why does this script determine these odd values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment `ps` runs a process `grep show_volume.sh` is also running, so you always count the grep!

Simple solution, `grep s[h]ow_volume.sh`.  The grep (not shell) will collapse the `[h]` to `h` and search for what you want, but your grep won't match itself because it will have [] in the parameter.

`pgrep` is also useful for this task and is smart enough to always exclude itself.

Comment: "At the moment ps runs a process grep show_volume.sh is also running" - not technically correct. there are cases in which `ps` will finish before `grep` fires up, in which case the `grep` won't be counted. so you have to cater for both cases.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't solve my problem. I tried to replace the expression with `pgrep show_volume.sh | wc -l` or `ps -a | grep s[h]ow_volume.sh | wc -l`, but the script behaves exactly the same as before.

Comment: @marcog, the reason I gave is the correct technical explanation for why he was getting 2 processes showing up in grep.  You're right, however, that in general you have to be ware that you may *not* get that behaviour depending on your system's performance characteristics.

Comment: @helios35, I suggest you examine the plain output of  `ps -a | grep s[h]ow_volume.sh` and work from there. (Personally I'd use `ps -ef | ...` to ensure you catch the case where the script is passed as a parameter to a shell)

Comment: `ps -ef | grep s[h]ow_volume.sh`


helios 25929 1 0 15:22 ? 00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/helios/scripts/show_volume.sh 
helios 25961 25929 0 15:22 ? 00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/helios/scripts/show_volume.sh

this is the output when I run the script once. I have no idea why there are 2 processes which don't really differ.

Comment: 2nd instance was launched by the first (PIDs show it's a child). Check your script carefully for a recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running the script as different users then `ps -a` will only show instances for the current user and only those with an attached terminal. Use `ps -ax` or `ps -e`.

```
pgrep -c
```

will show a count without having to use `wc`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to exclude grep as well, as your grep itself also contains `show_volume.sh`, an example

```
ps -a | grep show_volume.sh | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks, but  this doesn't change the behaviour of the script. The same error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by ajreal:

ps -a | grep show_volume.sh | grep -v grep | wc -l

should work. If it does not, please provide output of

ps -a | grep show_volume.sh | grep -v grep

here

Comment: output: "ps -e | grep show_volume.sh | grep -v grep"
15956 ? 00:00:00 show_volume.sh 
15971 ? 00:00:00 show_volume.sh
two processes although I executed the script only once and excluded grep.

Comment: `grep -v grep` is an antipattern.  How to avoid it is an ancient FAQ.